# Intelligent web scraping c#

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping

Theres a number of products out there that provide a gui to pick out the tags you want to scrape from a web page. (Things like WebHarvy for example)

I've seen the HTML Agility Pack before for getting at the DOM.
I just wanted to check if anyone knows of any nice libraries or processes for automatically finding the useful content within a HTML page and creating the XPath required.

Similar to how Evernote and iOS know where the "Article" is on a page. However ideally working for repeating regions and pagination.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for:
http://www.diffbot.com/

But Diffbot is good in scraping content from websites.

Comment: I'm after a library or something that can be built into my own solution. Not really wanting to rely on a 3rd party.

Comment: I've used Agility Pack, didn't find something more powerful in the past. But would be very interested if you find something better.